# sqlite error step 19 iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

what is wrong here?

I need use sqlite bind, because I want add HTML tags to sqlite database.

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    const char *sql = "INSERT INTO News (id,title,description,date,removed) VALUES (?,?,\"asd\",1,0);";

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 0, 2);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [@"test_binf" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE) {

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error on step: %i",sqlite3_errcode(database));
        }

        sqlite3_reset(stmt);
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error on prepare: %i",sqlite3_errcode(database));
    }
```

I got sqlite error: "Error on step: 19".

Please help me.

Comment: Use `sqlite3_errmsg` to see the actual error. But according to sqlite.org, error 19 is a constraint violation. The error message will make it clear.

Comment: FYI - No need to call `sqlite3_reset` on your statement in this case. The "finalize" is all you need.

Comment: I saw this code don't work with HTML tag.
Any suggestion how to insert html into sqlite (iOS)?
On Android I can use ContentValues

Comment: 1) What does HTML have to do with the error in your question? 2) Of course your code works with HTML. Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) says:

> The leftmost SQL parameter has an index of 1.

You must use indexes 1 and 2.